# Когда в русском языке появились слова "гардины, шторы, портьеры"?

Tags: этимология, лексика

У этих слов есть простой русский аналог — занавески. Тем не менее мы активно используем эти заимствованные слова, причем, как говорят, **не всегда правильно.**

https://tuavo.com/ru/shtory-gardiny-tyul-portery/

С другой стороны, в толковом словаре мы видим несколько **другое значение**, чем в приведенной статье:

**ШТОРА,** -ы; ж. [франц. store] Оконная занавеска, отодвигаемая в сторону и поднимаемая кверху (обычно при помощи шнура). Поднять, опустить штору (шторы). Задёрнуть шторы.

**ГАРДИНА**, -ы; ж. [нем. Gardine]. Занавеска, закрывающая всё окно.

**ПОРТЬЕРА**, -ы; ж. [франц. portière] Занавес из тяжёлой материи на дверях или окнах.

А когда эти слова вошли в русский язык и **сразу ли они приобрели современное значение?**

Например, в стихотворении Пастернака "Никого не будет дома..." упоминаются **и гардины, и портьеры.**

Это один и тот же предмет или на окне висят и гардины, и портьеры?

Но ведь гардины - это полупрозрачная ткань, она пропускает свет, даже если они задернуты.

А почему они не задернуты? Некоторые критики обращают на это внимание: "Сами незадёрнутые гардины – знак непорядка в доме лирического героя, отсутствие в его жизни уюта".https://avosya.ru/sochinenij/analiz-stihotvorenij/nikogo-ne-budet-v-dome-pasternak-b/

**Важна ли эта деталь** для понимания смысла стихотворения?

И что висело на окнах, например,  во времена Пушкина?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово «занавески» упоминается в  корпусе русского языка, начиная с 1789 г. и насчитывает 1588 вхождений. Для сравнения, слова: «шторы» - с  1821 г. (1228 вх.), «гардины» - с  1786 г. (191 вх.), «портьеры» - с 1847 г. (456 вх.).

Судя по этим датам все четыре слова появились в русском языке примерно в одно время.

На французском «дверь» – porte, а «привратник» - portier, gardien. Надо полагать, что портьеры и гардины к нам пришли оттуда. Не исключено, что слово «шторы» явилось нам из Голландии.

Примеры из корпуса русского языка:

«Одна из дверей в залу, прямо из коридора, была завешена огромными двойными портьерами из пунцового бархата. [Ф. М. Достоевский. Неточка Незванова (1849)]»

«…ее отвозил домой по утру рано и хотел, для сохранения чести ее, и более чтобы не учинилось известно сие графине Елисавете Романовне, закрывши гардины ехать, она, напротив того, открывая гардины, хотела всем показать, что она с Государем ночь переспала. [М. М. Щербатов. О повреждении нравов в России (1786-1787)]»

«Деревья сии отнимают, однако же, солнце у жителей, живущих в вечном сумраке, усугубляемом вечно опущенными до половины шторами. [Н. А. Бестужев. Записки о Голландии 1815 года (1821)]»